# Trying to get an if else statement to work in Java script on Code academy

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and I am learning Java script on Code academy my instructions are "Write your own if / else statement. The only instruction is that the result of evaluating the statement is a log to the console of "I finished my first course!". I get thrown with the error message Oops, try again. It looks like you didn't log anything! 
This is my code

```
if (7 == 7)
    console.log=("I finished my first course!");


else
    console.log=("Meh!");
```

I am confused as it prints out what is supposed to and I even tried running it in a different browser and was given same error message.

Comment: `console.log` is a method, not a value. You will want to do: `console.log("I finished my first course!")`.

Comment: `console.log("I finished my first course!");`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, Though we can override it ;) Syntactically this is correct !

Comment: @Rayon Well you can overwrite almost anything, but it doesn't mean you should. I'm not saying it's syntactically wrong, just pointing out that they should not be assigning strings to it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek — Yes! You are right...

Comment: I have changed my code to     if (7 == 7){
    console.log("I finished my first course!");
}

else{
    console.log("Meh!");
} Still given an error message would you agree the code is now correct though?

Answer (score 4):

You will later learn that the console is an Object, and objects have methods, like a car has a function to accelerate, so you access the accelerate function of the car using dot notation, like this: "car.accelerate()". In this case you are using the log method of the console, in this manner "console.log()", so you don't need the equal sign because you are not setting any variable.

```
console.log("message goes here");
```

Please refer to the javascript documentation by mozilla for more info.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Take out the = in your console.log method.

```
if (7 == 7)
console.log("I finished my first course!");

else
    console.log("Meh!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for your purpose.

```
if (7 == 7) {
    console.log("I finished my first course!");
}
else {
    console.log("Meh!");
}
```

Comment: What OP has coded is not invalid/wrong syntax..

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it gives the error of TypeError: console.log is not a function. :/

Comment: The code is correct. You can try with writing a simple html and javascript file and run that in browser.

Comment: @Melmet `console.log` is a function. If you state `console.log = "somestr"`, you are overwritting that function with a string. Hence it will no longer work elsewhere in the code, that's why you get that error.

Comment: Or you can try scratchpad of firefox to test your code.

Comment: I think the error you are getting is specific to the codeAcadamy

Comment: Lot of users has already faced this issue on CodeAcademy. https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/4fcf371548006500030445ef

Answer (score -1):

if (7 == 7) 
   { console.log("I finished my first course!");}

else {
    console.log("Meh!");}

That seems to work thanks.